# Divide total sum equally to higher sampled time periods when upsampling with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to distribute the total sum of a time period evenly to the components of the higher sampled time period.

What I did:

```
>>> rng = pandas.PeriodIndex(start='2014-01-01', periods=2, freq='W')
>>> ts = pandas.Series([i+1 for i in range(len(rng))], index=rng)
>>> ts
2013-12-30/2014-01-05    1
2014-01-06/2014-01-12    2
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: float64

>>> ts.resample('D')
2013-12-30     1
2013-12-31   NaN
2014-01-01   NaN
2014-01-02   NaN
2014-01-03   NaN
2014-01-04   NaN
2014-01-05   NaN
2014-01-06     2
2014-01-07   NaN
2014-01-08   NaN
2014-01-09   NaN
2014-01-10   NaN
2014-01-11   NaN
2014-01-12   NaN
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

What I actually want is:

```
>>> ts.resample('D', some_miracle_thing)
2013-12-30     1/7
2013-12-31     1/7
2014-01-01     1/7
2014-01-02     1/7
2014-01-03     1/7
2014-01-04     1/7
2014-01-05     1/7
2014-01-06     2/7
2014-01-07     2/7
2014-01-08     2/7
2014-01-09     2/7
2014-01-10     2/7
2014-01-11     2/7
2014-01-12     2/7
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to do it

1. Specifically – e.g., with a `x/7` lambda function?
2. Generically, so it works independently of the factor 7 (say 24 for hours to days and so on)?

Comment: Five years later, is there any better more standardized solution?

Answer (score 6):

A little convoluted, but does this work?

First, when you resample, add a `.groupby(level=0)` so the original timestamp is preserved.  (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898574/resample-intraday-pandas-dataframe-without-add-new-days))

```
rs = ts.groupby(level=0).resample('D')
```

Then apply a groupby on the first level of the MultiIndex to apply the operation you want.

```
In [285]: rs.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / float(len(x)))
Out[285]: 
2013-12-30/2014-01-05  2013-12-30    0.142857
                       2013-12-31    0.142857
                       2014-01-01    0.142857
                       2014-01-02    0.142857
                       2014-01-03    0.142857
                       2014-01-04    0.142857
                       2014-01-05    0.142857
2014-01-06/2014-01-12  2014-01-06    0.285714
                       2014-01-07    0.285714
                       2014-01-08    0.285714
                       2014-01-09    0.285714
                       2014-01-10    0.285714
                       2014-01-11    0.285714
                       2014-01-12    0.285714
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Looks good, but I am a little depressed that this basic functionality has no easy to use implementation. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This works, but I find it ugly:

```
>>> rs = ts.resample('D', fill_method="pad")
>>> rs/7

2013-12-30    0.142857
2013-12-31    0.142857
2014-01-01    0.142857
2014-01-02    0.142857
2014-01-03    0.142857
2014-01-04    0.142857
2014-01-05    0.142857
2014-01-06    0.285714
2014-01-07    0.285714
2014-01-08    0.285714
2014-01-09    0.285714
2014-01-10    0.285714
2014-01-11    0.285714
2014-01-12    0.285714
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Is there no internal function for this basic functionality?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I hate this solution, but it works for upsampling when you're unsure of the number of new intervals.  Going from week to day is easy, it's always 7 days / week.  But I've found the number of intervals based on an upsample is usually unknown - this solution works for that.

The idea is to get the number of post-resample intervals into the initial pre-resampled dataframe, then re-resample and divide your data by the interval count.  Side note - this is for a dataframe, not a series.

```
# Create unique group IDs by simply using the existing index (Assumes an integer, non-duplicated index)
df['group'] = df.index  

# Get the count of intervals for each post-resampled timestamp.
df['count'] = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('15min').ffill()['group'].value_counts()

# Resample all data again and fill so that the count is now included in every row.
df          = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('15min').ffill()

# Apply the division on the entire dataframe and clean up.
df          = df.div(df['count'], axis = 0).reset_index().drop(['group','count'], axis = 1)
```

I'd wrap this in a function and tuck it away so I never have to look at it again, with something like:

`def distribute_upsample(df, index, freq)`

Where `index` would be `'timestamp'` and `freq` would be `'15min'`